# Where Clause ARRAY in PHP - MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have one problem for Where clause in PHP - MongoDB.

i search in this forum and obtain some information.

My code is :

```
$condizioneMongoDB = "array('chrom'=>'chr7' )";
$whereClause = eval("\$str = \"$condizioneMongoDB\";");
$retval = $collection->distinct("p_id", $whereClause);
```

The Where clause is completely ignored.

This static code work:

```
$retval = $collection->distinct("p_id", array('chrom'=>'chr7' ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $whereClause = eval("\$str = \"$condizioneMongoDB\";");

it is equal to `$str = "array('chrom'=>'chr7' )"`,
but you want `$str = array('chrom'=>'chr7')`

You should to omit quotes for this.

Also, you need to return value from eval to use it, or you can use variable from `eval` directly.

```
$condizioneMongoDB = "array('chrom'=>'chr7' )";
$whereClause = eval("return $condizioneMongoDB;");
$retval = $collection->distinct("p_id", $whereClause);
```

Or:

```
$condizioneMongoDB = "array('chrom'=>'chr7' )";
eval("\$whereClause = $condizioneMongoDB;");
$retval = $collection->distinct("p_id", $whereClause);
```

Comment: i don't know why but if i write var_dump($whereClause); i obtain NULL

Comment: I add explanation about this. You didn't return anything from `eval`.

Comment: the second option seems to work perfectly thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this line is looks wrong

```
$condizioneMongoDB = "array('chrom'=>'chr7' )";
```

Why are you putting array in double quotes? Change it like following

```
 $condizioneMongoDB = array('chrom'=>'chr7' );
```

Comment: thank's for answer . I obtain this string by form . The line with eval transform in array

Comment: $collection->distinct is taking second argument as array not string so passing array in string it is not working any more

Comment: I transform in array with this line $whereClause = eval("\$str = \"$condizioneMongoDB\";");

Comment: after eval array is not display from assigned variable

Comment: yes sorry in this post i simplify the answer but i get in input a string